# Normalize target value for linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, transform, normalization

I'm building a regression model to predict sensor value over time.
Bellow is a figure of my sensors data over time:
[image]

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1H4j97paI4&feature=youtu.be) about transforming nonlinear data with a log function, What function can I use to try and flatten the curved behavior into a linear line?

Comment: Is time the only labeling of the data? i.e., all you know is X (time) and Y (value?) Do you know anything else about the behavior of the sensors - any relevant domain knowledge?

Comment: I do have more features that describe the point i.e F(feature 1, ... ,feature n) = score

Comment: in the video `y` and `x` had an approximate exponential relation and taking `log` made it linear. In your case, you would first need to fit a curve to your data and then think about "neutralizing" your base of exponents, so to speak, using a suitable function. For example if you'd encounter `2^x` as the curve function, you would want to take logarithm to the base 2

Answer (score 1):

**First option:**
If you want to have some log scaling like we see in video, you need to scale $x$ axis, not $y$. The reason is that you have function that "behave" opposite to function in video - it's derivative is decreasing, so you need to make bigger $\Delta x$ "step" to keep $\Delta y$ the same.

The answer:
You need to select appropriate base $b$ for $log_b$ and scale your $x$ axis to with $log_b$. If you have more than one feature, you may need to have different $b$ for features. Or, if you

*This is not a trivial task to do, especially if there are the many features that impact on $y$ in different ways and interact with each other. It's the reason why I give you the second option.*

**Second option:**
You can solve this problem with linear regression methods using nonlinear features. Now you have only one set of features - $x$. You can calculate some nonlinear features from $x$ and treat the problem like linear regression over $x$ and the new features.
For example, you can use $\sqrt x$ as feature for your data.

There is more general approach - **polynomial features**. It means you can use all indeterminates of polynom as features and get regression coefficients like if it's linear problem (for example, you can use analytic solution for it). For polynomial features you can use PolynomialFeatures() class of scikit-learn library (for Python), or just solve matrix equations.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
...
X # your features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2) # add features from degree-2 polynom
new_features = poly.fit_transform(X) # your new features
```

I hope this will be helpful!